# Ant ReplaceRegExp task changing a line it shouldn't

Tags: regex, ant, build

I was updating an xml file with a version/build number. It was working just fine but then a developer put in some new lines of code and for some reason one of those lines gets changed. 
Here is my regex:

```
`<replaceregexp file="${basedir}Monitors\Invos\Trunk\InvosWPF\InvosSettings.xml"
match="&lt;ConfigurationVersion value=\&quot;[0-9.]* "
replace="&lt;ConfigurationVersion value=\&quot;${ver_bldnum}"
byline="false"/>`
```

Its messing with ChannelLabel2 value. Before the regex:
    `<ChannelLabels>
      <ChannelLabel0 value="L"/>
      <ChannelLabel1 value="R"/>
      <ChannelLabel2 value="Sâ‚"/>
      <ChannelLabel3 value="Sâ‚‚"/>
    </ChannelLabels>`

After the regex:
    `<ChannelLabels>
      <ChannelLabel0 value="L"/>
      <ChannelLabel1 value="R"/>
      <ChannelLabel2 value="Sâ‚?"/>
      <ChannelLabel3 value="Sâ‚‚"/>
     </ChannelLabels>`

Its inserting a ? for some reason. The only line I want it to change is:

```
`<ConfigurationVersion value="1.0.0.92" />`
```

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Comment: Could the question mark be a not-encodable character and the line contains a character that is not readable by the default encoding of the machine running the Ant task?  Without specifying any encoding, Ant will assume the platform's default encoding for in- and output.

Comment: Several questions: 1) Why `byline="false"`? 2) Did you intend to have the space character in the `[0-9.]* "` part of `match` (between the `*` and the `"`)? Your example input doesn't have a space before the closing quotation mark: `1.0.0.92"`.

Comment: No good reason for the byline. The file has the space there so I put it in my regex. I'll admit to being awful at regex. The strange thing is if the Version string doesn't match then the ChannelLabel2 doesn't get changed. However if the version string is changed then so is ChannelLabel2. When I look at the xml file in notepad++ the special 'a' shows up as a square.